# Calling a C++ function from C# - structs, pointers, function pointers

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, interop

I'm currently trying to integrate a C++ DLL into our C# application, but I'm not able to identify  the correct way to call one of their methods.

C++ methods definition:

```
typedef struct ImageDataAndInfo
{ 
    unsigned char* PicBuffer;     //image buffer 
    long lPicSize;    //image data length 
    int iPicType;     // iPicType, 0: bmp, 1: tiff, 2: jpeg 
} ImageDataAndInfo,*PImageDataAndInfo; 

typedef  ImageAndScanError    (__stdcall * ReadPictureData)(PImageDataAndInfo PicF1,
    PImageDataAndInfo PicR1, 
    PImageDataAndInfo PicF2,
    PImageDataAndInfo PicR2,  
    PImageDataAndInfo PicF3,
    PImageDataAndInfo PicR3,  
    BOOL bSourceBMPSave);

typedef  void    (__stdcall * FreeImageDataBuffer)(PImageDataAndInfo pImageDataAndInfo);
```

C++ example code:

```
ImageDataAndInfo F1,F2,F3,R1,R2,R3;
F1.lPicSize=0;
F2.lPicSize=0;
F3.lPicSize=0;
R1.lPicSize=0;
R2.lPicSize=0;
R3.lPicSize=0;

int bResult;
bResult=ReadPictureData(&F1,&R1,&F2,&R2,&F3,&R3,TRUE);

f_FreeImageDataBuffer(&F1);
...
f_FreeImageDataBuffer(&R3);
```

My C# conversion:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct PImageDataAndInfo
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray)]
    public byte[] PicBuffer;        //image buffer 

    public int lPicSize;            //image data length 
    public int iPicType;            // iPicType, 0: bmp, 1: tiff, 2: jpeg 
}

[DllImport("ScanDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
public static extern ImageAndScanError ReadPictureData(
    out PImageDataAndInfo PicF1,
    out PImageDataAndInfo PicR1,
    out PImageDataAndInfo PicF2,
    out PImageDataAndInfo PicR2,
    out PImageDataAndInfo PicF3,
    out PImageDataAndInfo PicR3,
    bool bSourceBMPSave);

PImageDataAndInfo PicF1 = new PImageDataAndInfo();
...
PImageDataAndInfo PicR3 = new PImageDataAndInfo();

ReadPictureData(
    out PicF1,
    out PicR1,
    out PicF2,
    out PicR2,
    out PicF3,
    out PicR3,
    false);
```

If I specify a default value for `PicBuffer`, using `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 99999)]`, I don't receive a value in `lPicSize`, and if I don't specify a default value I get a value in `lPicSize` but it isn't the correct value for `PicBuffer`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It's been a while since I did C++ but IMHO the C++ code declares a function pointer, not a method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The native DLL is allocating the memory for the buffer, and returning the unmanaged pointer in the `PicBuffer` field of the struct. And so your struct declaration is wrong. You need the byte array to be declared as a pointer.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ImageDataAndInfo
{
    public IntPtr PicBuffer;       
    public int lPicSize;           
    public int iPicType;           
}
```

The you must call [`Marshal.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146631.aspx) to copy the buffer's content to a byte array. For example:

```
// call ReadPictureData
byte[] buffer = new byte[PicF1.lPicSize];
Marshal.Copy(PicF1.PicBuffer, buffer, 0, PicF1.lPicSize);
```

Make sure you call `FreeImageDataBuffer` when you have copied all the buffers. Otherwise you will leak the memory that the native DLL allocated.

---

Note that in the C++ code, `ImageDataAndInfo` is the struct and `PImageDataAndInfo` is a pointer to the struct. So your C# struct should be named `ImageDataAndInfo`.

Also, you do not need to use `new` to make new instances of a struct. Just declare them like this:

```
ImageDataAndInfo PicF1;
ImageDataAndInfo PicF2;
// etc.
```